# Error 400 trying to login with Facebook using Android web view

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I did force my app to login always using the web view using the Facebook SDK (4.7.0). For the user that I'm facing the problem (for some reason that I'm still trying to figure out why) I get a null object and the following answer on the Facebook GraphRequest callback:

`{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument}}`

Using the same user in other devices and log in with other users in the problematic device, it works. Does anybody have an idea what can be wrong?

Comment: I found the problem, it was happening because I was log in with a different user in my app of the user that was logged in in the Facebook App, I just logout() every time before log in, it solved the problem. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31562542/3850821